# Electric guitar's 6th string buzzing, but through the amplifier, the buzz sound is not coming. Anything to be concerned about?

Tags: electric-guitar, tuning, intonation, buzz

I just bought a new Cort Les Paul electric guitar.
Except for the 6th string, all other strings are working fine. No buzzing.
But the 6th string (fattest one), on plucking, is buzzing when not connected to the amplifier. However, the buzz sound is not coming through the amplifier when it is connected.

So considering the above scenario, is there anything wrong with the guitar's 6th string? Or is this buzzing sound a normal thing to happen?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the buzzing when the open string is played, or on particular frets, or what? You could raise the bridge/saddle for that string, or on that side, a little, but if it's not coming through the amp., don't worry, unless it gets louder. Maybe  a reason to take it back for checking - it's what should happen with potentially faulty goods.

Comment: @Tim I just checked by connecting my headphone. The buzz sound is also noticeable in the headphone audio. On 5th string (very little) and 6th string (significant). On playing open note or open string, there is no buzz sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On that guitar, there *should* be an adjustable saddle, where the string goes over the bridge. You should have a small Allen (hex) key, which fits into small holes on either side of that saddle. Screwing clockwise will raise the string's height, and you'll reach a point where the buzzing stops.